# UITableView not populated. Item size is 2

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm in the process of making a small app for myself to try out Swift and so forth, and I think I am missing something simple here.

So in my controller, i have the proper delegates and methods to support it:

```
class MatchListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

I then setup & populate the table

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    loadResults()
}

func loadResults() {
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext! = delegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Series")
    var error:NSError? = nil
    results = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as NSArray
}
```

In Storyboard, the UITableView is connected to my IBOutlet, and refers to MatchListViewController as its delegate.

```
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
```

I setup the cellForRowAtIndexPath method as such:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
    if let row = indexPath?.row {
        let object = results.objectAtIndex(row) as NSObject
        if (object != nil) {
            let teamOneName = object.valueForKey("team_one") as NSString
            let teamTwoName = object.valueForKey("team_two") as NSString
            cell.textLabel!.text = "\(teamOneName) vs \(teamTwoName)"
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Any ideas on what I may be missing here?

Comment: You said you connected the delegate - did you also connect the data source?

Comment: Did you wire up your table view delegate and datasource in IB?

Comment: Yep, datasource & delegate point to the view controller in IB

Comment: Here's a screenshot if it helps: http://i.imgur.com/yixskoc.png

Comment: And you overrode `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: Yep, returning `results.count`. Can see my full code if you wish: https://github.com/agmcleod/BracketTracker/blob/master/BracketTracker/MatchListViewController.swift. Thanks!

Comment: Further update. if i log out the string i set to the `cell.textLabel.text = `, I can see the data being output, so it is modifying the cell label.

Comment: HMm, i think it may of been a layout issue actually. I looked at it using iPhone 5s and couldnt see anything, but noticed the draw width of the row was 800px. In iPad simulator i didnt see anything, but the row count was zero (different data set). Fixed my autolayout to resize better, can see it on iPhone 5s sim now.